# How to allow access to secondary files only from the main pages of the site?

Tags: php, html, apache, http

I have three hosted files (index.php, estilo.css, logotipo.jpg). I want the file "index.php" to be accessible by anyone, but the "estilo.css and logotipo.jpg" files can only be accessed by the "index.php" file and never directly. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Your `estilo.css` and `logotypo.jpg` files will _never_ be accessed by `index.php`; they will always be accessed directly. That's how web browsers work. My browser will process the output of `index.php` and see references for the other two files. Then it will request them directly from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the PHP file is not sent to the user.

The PHP file actually generates an HTML file, that is send to the browser. If this HTML contains CSS & Javascript files (via script and link elements), the the browser requests the files.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I just managed to regularize the security of my website just by studying how the file works. HTACCESS.